# Getting R (radius) value from PostGIS layer

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to get the "r" value and put in the table as attribute? This is a PostGIS layer.

[image]

I tried this code but the results are different.

```
sqrt( 
    ( $x_at(1) - ($x_at(-1) + $x_at(0) )/2 )^2 
    + ( $y_at(1) - ($y_at(-1) + $y_at(0))/2 )^2
     ) /2
+
( ( $x_at(-1) - $x_at(0) )^2   +  ( $y_at(-1) - $y_at(0) )^2 )
/ ( 8 * sqrt(
            ( ($x_at(1) - ($x_at(-1) + $x_at(0) )/2 )^2
            + ( $y_at(1) - ($y_at(-1) + $y_at(0) )/2 )^2
             )))
```

Comment: `-1` is not going to work for `CIRCULARSTRING`s with more than 3 vertices - in that case you'd need to loop over the vertices (2-step, beginning with [0-based] index 1) and apply the above calculations on the relative index positions. Note that arcs may be subject to coordinate coercion to realize curvation, so that actual radii of the described circles may vary.